# separate the saved output of command that process a very large compressed JSON file

Tags: json, linux, csv, command, jq

Ok, let's start with the command line that i'm using:

```
curl --silent http://example.com/json.gz | pigz -dc | jq -r '[.name, .value] | @csv' > data.csv
```

CURL will download a compressed of 11.6 GB of JSON file, `pigz` will decompress it and write all processed output to stdout, `jq` will read JSON and save the output as csv file.

The problem is, the output that saved as data.csv is extremely large and after all i still need to analyze this data by using a PHP script and insert it to MYSQL in special format (the data will have very small size then)

But, i only have less than 60 GB free space left in my server, even i'm not able to decompress the full data and save it to the CSV file.

So, i got an idea, if i'm able to save the output to separated files that have different names (let's say the names are the current date or timestamp) then i can run the PHP script to process every .csv file of them and save data to db and then delete the file to free the space, not sure if this is the best way, but at least i'm trying to make it work.

So, i modified my command line to:

```
curl --silent http://example.com/json.gz | pigz -dc | jq -r '[.name, .value] | @csv' > `date +"%S-%M-%d-%m-%Y"`_data.csv
```

But, it saved it all in one file only, i thought it will save it as multi files that everyone of them have different name since the date will keep changing while the output is written.

Also, any other working solutions are welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### save space with GNU `split --filter`

POSIX `split` creates output files from its input and so requires a lot of free space to store them (the size of the entire uncompressed input plus some overhead).

However, the GNU version of `split` has an extra `--filter` option which allows processing individual chunks of data in much less space as it does not need to create any temporary files:

```
| split -l $NUMLINES --filter='shell_command'
```

You can think of it like `xargs -n $NUMLINES command` except passing data to stdin instead of as commandline arguments.

For example, to output the md5sum of each set of (up to) 7 lines of /etc/passwd and then output the number of chunks processed:

```
</etc/passwd split -l7 --filter='md5sum|tee /dev/tty' |\
{ echo Processed $(wc -l) chunks; }
```

To modify your command to work on 10000 lines at a time, you could do something like:

```
curl -L --silent "$URL" |\
pigz -dc |\
jq -r '[.name, .value] | @csv' |\
split -l 10000 --filter='save2db.php'
```

Your filter command `save2db.php` should read from stdin.

If you prefer to make it read from an actual file, you can do something like:

```
... |\
split -l 10000 --filter='cat >TMPFILE; save2db.php TMPFILE';
rm TMPFILE
```

---

**Warning:** You'll need to ensure that it is safe to split your csv file on line boundaries. Some csv files contain fields with embedded literal newlines; they may become malformed if split mid-field.

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `split` command, see [man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html)

Simple example (10MB to STDOUT):

`# dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=10 | split - --bytes=1M -d -a3 out`

Output files (10 files with size of 1MB read from STDIN):

```
# stat -c "%s %n" out00*
1048576 out000
1048576 out001
1048576 out002
1048576 out003
1048576 out004
1048576 out005
1048576 out006
1048576 out007
1048576 out008
1048576 out009
```

Or split the saved file with `split --bytes=1M -d -a3 out out`

Output:

```
# stat -c "%s %n" out*
10485760 out
1048576 out000
1048576 out001
1048576 out002
1048576 out003
1048576 out004
1048576 out005
1048576 out006
1048576 out007
1048576 out008
1048576 out009
```

Comment: or use `split` with `--lines=NUMBER` (NUMBER lines/records per output file)

Comment: You were right, using `split` is the way to do that, +1 thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a program such as `awk` to do the partitioning, e.g. like so:

```
jq -rc '[.id, .value] | @csv' |
  awk -v NUM 100000 '{n++; print > "out." int((n+NUM)/NUM) ".csv"}'
```

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work with me, i edited the question, now the live link is there, i also offered a bounty for it, thank you for helping me.

Comment: I don't see a live link, nor do I see anything about the nature of the difficulty you're facing.  Does your awk have `int()`?

Comment: You could simply pipe the JSON into the command-line as shown, and redirect the output as you have done.  To avoid trouble, though, I'd suggest creating a script, and maybe using a small test file.